# Presence / absence of an outgoing edge from a vertex in OrientDb

Tags: graph-databases, orientdb

I have seen some similar questions on SO but none of the answers have worked for me yet, so I am hoping to get a new answer with the new features that have been added to recent versions of OrientDb since the other questions were asked.

I am trying to query all vertices which have an outgoing edge of a particular type but no outgoing edge of another type.

As an example in a simple relationship of

Person ---- Friend ---> Person

Person ---- Owns   ---> Car

I am trying to find all the persons who have friends but do not own a car.

I have already tried the following query with no luck (It returns all the persons irrespective of whether or not those vertices have an outgoing edge of a particular kind)

```
select from Person where (out('Friend') not null and out('Owns').size() = 0)
select from Person where (out('Friend') is not null and out('Owns') is null)
```

In my efforts I realized that the NOT query is not supported yet by OrientDb in the WHERE clause as per this page: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Where 
Can someone please verify if this is indeed true.

Anyways, I moved on and tried to simplify my query and tried to find only vertices that do not have the outgoing edge of 'Owns'. Even that did not work in that it seemed to return all the Person vertices in my graph:

```
select from Person where (out('Owns').size() = 0)
select from Person where (out('Owns') is null)
```

Not sure what I am missing, but any help is as always greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try working always with size, like this:

```
select from Person where outE('Friend').size() > 0 and outE('Owns').size() = 0
```

Comment: Luca, That seems to work. Thank you. I noticed you using outE and out on separate occasions in your query above.  Both seem to work for me. Is there a difference between when we should be using which one?

Also, is the null query recognized in orient. It does not give an error when it tries to execute the query, so is there a particular time when we use it. Could you please give an example when we might be able to use null. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed the query: outE is cheaper than out, because you stop on evaluating edges without loading the attached vertices. But works both. About the NULL you don't know when a collection is NULL or just empty (after a delete), so it's better to use size() that in case of null should be 0.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. Accepted your answer now :)

Answer (score -2):

however, my queries return differently
select from customer where outE('email').size() > 0;
0 items

select from customer where outE('email') is not NULL;
many items returned

looks to me "size() > 0" is not the same as "is not NULL"

sorry if I am wrong