# OrientDb How to return vertices that have specific edges?

Tags: orientdb

Example I have a notification vertex this notification can be generated by many types or followed  by many types but I want to get a notification generated by some condition only...I could do this by going from the other class and getting outgoing notification vertex from that class...is this good practice?I am new to orientdb...appreciate all the help

maybe something like this

```
select  from notification where outE = 'followed'
```

this returns nothing in the UI

Comment: Have you searched about it?

Comment: yes I have searched for it

Answer (score 0):

so I found the answer in another question
[Presence / absence of an outgoing edge from a vertex in OrientDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690108/presence-absence-of-an-outgoing-edge-from-a-vertex-in-orientdb?rq=1)

so this will work like this

```
select from notification where outE('follows').size()> 0
```